# Android custom url works from href but not directly

Tags: android

I have defined a custom url for my Android application:

```
<intent-filter>
  <data android:scheme="myfoo" /> 
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" /> 
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
</intent-filter>
```

When I create a web page that has

```
<a href="myfoo://">My Foo</a>
```

and click on the link from the local browser, my application is launched just fine. However, if I type "myfoo://" directly in the browser, it simply takes me to Google's search listing.

Wondering if there is a setting on the default browser that I need to disable to make my custom url work. Regards.

Comment: By default browser, are you refering to the "stock" App called "Browser" that comes with your Android OS? What phone brand do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Wondering if there is a setting on the default browser that I need to disable to make my custom url work.

Probably not. For starters, there is no single "default browser" in Android. Beyond that, browser developers are welcome to do whatever they want with URLs, including having varying behavior based upon where the URL comes from (address bar vs. link vs. JavaScript vs. ...).